# Show that $|z + w|^2 = |z|^2 + |w|^2 + 2\text{Re}(z\bar w)$ for any $z, w \in \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I prove the above?

Thank you

Comment: You... Run the calcs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $|z|^2=z\bar z$ and that $z+\bar z=2\text{Re}(z)$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
|z+w|^2&=(z+w)\overline{(z+w)}\\\\
&=(z+w)(\bar z+\bar w)\\\\
&=z\bar z+w\bar w+(z\bar w+\bar z w)\\\\
&=|z|^2+|w|^2+(z\bar w+\overline{z \bar w})\\\\
&=|z|^2+|w|^2+2\text{Re}(z\bar w)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Answer (score 2):

Just calculate
\begin{align}\lvert z+w\rvert^2&=(z+w)(\overline{z+w})=(z+w)(\bar z+\overline w)\\
&=z\bar z+w\overline w+z\overline w+\bar z w\\
&=\lvert z\rvert^2+\lvert w\rvert^2+z\overline w+\bar z w
\end{align}
Now, as $z\overline w$ and $\bar z w$ are conjugate, their sum is twice their common real part.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
|z+w|^2=(z+w)\overline{(z+w)}=(z+w)(\bar z+\bar w)=z\bar z+w\bar w+z\bar w+w\bar z=|z|^2+|w|^2+z\bar w+\overline {z\bar w}=|z|^2+|w|^2+2\Re(z\bar w)
\end{equation}